# Unable in my attempt to retrieve google api data using httpget

Tags: android, api, google-api, google-places-api, http-get

I am trying to get data from Google Places API. However, the problem in my code is that I simply dont get any data back from http client.

I see nothing in the textbox (which should be getting the response from the Google API)

**Java File Code:**

```
public class Httpexample extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

TextView tv_ResponseAPI;
Button btn_GetResponse;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.api_example);



    tv_ResponseAPI = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_ResponseAPI);
    btn_GetResponse = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_GetResponse);
        btn_GetResponse.setOnClickListener(this);

    Log.v("Http", "entered the onCreate function");

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.btn_GetResponse:
        Log.v("Http", "Button was clicked");

        //tv_ResponseAPI.setText("Button was clicked");
        getInternetdata();          
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

}

public void getInternetdata() {

    Log.v("Http", "Entered getInternetData()");
    try {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&types=food&name=harbour&sensor=false&key=my_api_here");
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);    
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        InputStream webs = entity.getContent();

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(webs, "iso-8859-1"), 8);

            tv_ResponseAPI.setText(reader.readLine());
            webs.close();

        } catch(Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tab", "Error Converting Result :" + e.toString());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tab", "Error in http connection :" + e.toString());
    }       
}


}
```

Even if my API Key (which i have checked) or something is messed up, I should be getting a JSON format response like the following right? I don't get anything. Putting breakpoints and debugging, program freezes and does nothing before the 'response' statement.

The URL in the httpget("...") is the example here: https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search

```
{
"html_attributions": [],
"results": [],
"status": "REQUEST_DENIED"
}
```

Comment: Don't get anything => Means there may be some issues, check your `logcat`

Comment: I was able to resolve the issue using AsyncTask. Since my API Level > 3.0, I think i needed to use that.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue using AsyncTask. Since my API Level > 3.0, I think i needed to use that.

I followed the code example at the following link as a guide to ping the Google Places API: http://hmkcode.com/android-internet-connection-using-http-get-httpclient/